# Why is Milton invoking Urania?

Tags: muses

The identity of the muse John Milton invokes in the opening of Book I in *Paradise Lost* is revealed in Book VII:

> Descend from Heav'n Urania, by that name
>   If rightly thou art call'd, whose Voice divine
>   Following, above th' Olympian Hill I soare,
>   Above the flight of Pegasean wing.
>
> <sub>Paradise Lost (1674)/Book VII. (2013, November 18). In Wikisource . Retrieved 07:53, March 27, 2017, from https://en.wikisource.org/w/index.php?title=Paradise_Lost_(1674)/Book_VII&oldid=4668224</sub>

Why is Milton seeking inspiration from the muse of astronomy?

Comment: I've attempted an answer based on the Milton text and a Classical source (Ovid) but it is probably worth asking on Lit also, b/c English Lit scholars would likely have more detail on Milton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say the following passage provides the direct answer:

> The meaning, not the Name I call: for thou
>   Nor of the Muses nine, nor on the top
>   Of old Olympus dwell'st, but Heav'nlie borne,
>   Before the Hills appeerd, or Fountain flow'd,
>   Thou with Eternal Wisdom didst converse...
>   <sub>Source: [Paradise Lost, Book 7, lines 5-9](https://en.wikisource.org/w/index.php?title=Paradise_Lost_(1674)/Book_VII&oldid=4668224)</sub>

Milton goes on to describe her as a guide for a journey to the heavens and safe return to earth:

> Up led by thee
>   Into the Heav'n of Heav'ns I have presum'd,
>   An Earthlie Guest, and drawn Empyreal Aire,

As Urania existed before "the Hills appeard", it makes sense to ask her of pre-historic events:

> Say Goddess, what ensu'd when Raphael,
>   The affable Arch-Angel, had forewarn'd
>   Adam by dire example to beware...

I don't claim to be an expert on Milton, but he seems to be invoking the primal form of Urania as an something of a personified prime mover (i.e. a natural law, although Newton's [Principia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophi%C3%A6_Naturalis_Principia_Mathematica) wouldn't be published for another 13 years.) Research into [Milton's philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Milton#Philosophy) may provide more insight.

It might also be worth looking at [Herodotus' Histories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histories_(Herodotus)#Book_VIII_.28Urania.29) because the work was at some point divided into sections, with Section 7 being named for [Urania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histories_(Herodotus)#Book_VIII_.28Urania.29) *(The [English and Greek texts can be found on Perseus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0126%3Abook%3D7%3Achapter%3D1%3Asection%3D1))*. I don't know if Milton would have had access to this specific text, but he did write in Greek and Latin...

However, simply based on Ovid's profound influence in Shakespeare, I have no doubt Milton knew Ovid intimately.  Ovid mentions Urania in his [Fasti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fasti):

> Polyhymnia ended. Clio and Thalia, mistress of the curved lyre, approved her words. Urania took up the tale; all kept silence and not a voice but hers could be heard. 
>   <sub>Source: [Ovid, Fasti, Book 5, line 53-55 (Frazer trans.)](http://www.theoi.com/Text/OvidFasti5.html) | [Latin Text available on Perseus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A2008.01.0547%3Abook%3D5)</sub>

Ovid has Urania comment on the reverence for the wisdom of elders in past eras:

> “Great was of old the reverence for the hoary head, and wrinkled eld was valued at its true worth. Martial exploits and doughty wars were work for youths, who in defence o their own gods kept watch and ward. In strength unequal, and for arms unfit, age often stood the country in good stead by its advice..."

Which seems to fit quite nicely with Milton's note that "[Urania] with Eternal Wisdom didst converse".

Comment: "The meaning, not the Name I call" may be an invitation to the reader to read the name etymologically, as the "Heavenly Muse" of the poem's initial invocation (1.6), rather than simply recalling that Hesiod includes the name in a list of the 9 Muses of Pieria ("old Olympus"). And that initial invocation further identifies the spirit in question with the "Spirit of God" that "moved upon the face of the waters" in Gen. 1.2: "thou from the first / Wast present, and, with mighty wings outspread, / Dove-like sat'st brooding on the vast Abyss, / And mad'st it pregnant" (1.19-22). Holy Ghost, then.